# XSL transformation from FMPXMLRESULT to FMRESULTSET (2 popular FileMaker grammars)

Tags: xml, xslt, filemaker

Thanks to Tomalak from Stackoverflow I was able to make a simple XSL transformation from the "old" FMPXMLRESULT xml grammar to the "new" FMRESULTSET xml grammar.

This is the original xml file with FMPXMLRESULT grammar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
<ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
<PRODUCT BUILD="06-20-2006" NAME="FileMaker Pro" VERSION="8.5v1"/>
<DATABASE DATEFORMAT="M/d/yyyy" LAYOUT="" NAME="pro_page.fp7" RECORDS="2121" TIMEFORMAT="h:mm:ss a"/>
<METADATA>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Ident" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Title" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Content" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Footnotes::Num" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Footnotes::Title" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Images::Num" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Images::FileName" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Images::Title" TYPE="TEXT"/>
</METADATA>
<RESULTSET FOUND="1">
    <ROW MODID="135" RECORDID="440">
        <COL><DATA>422</DATA></COL>
        <COL><DATA>title text here</DATA></COL>
        <COL><DATA>some more text here</DATA></COL>
        <COL>
            <DATA>1</DATA>
            <DATA>2</DATA>
            <DATA>3</DATA>
            <DATA>4</DATA>
        </COL>
        <COL>
            <DATA>footnote 1 text here</DATA>
            <DATA>footnote 2 text here</DATA>
            <DATA>footnote 3 text here</DATA>
            <DATA>footnote 4 text here</DATA>
        </COL>
        <COL>
            <DATA>457</DATA>
            <DATA>563</DATA>
        </COL>
        <COL>
            <DATA>image 1 url here</DATA>
            <DATA>image 2 url here</DATA>
        </COL>
        <COL>
            <DATA>title for image 1 here</DATA>
            <DATA>title for image 2 here</DATA>
        </COL>
    </ROW>
</RESULTSET>
```

This is the FMRESULTSET format I'm trying to get (note: I don't need the complete "metadata" section, it can be left empty, and I removed some attributes I don't need either):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fmresultset version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/xml/fmresultset">
<error code="0"/>
<product version="8.0.4.128" name="FileMaker Web Publishing Engine" build="06/14/2006"/>
<datasource total-count="2121" timestamp-format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" time-format="HH:mm:ss" table="pro_page" layout="MR_Page_An" date-format="MM/dd/yyyy" database="pro_page.fp7"/>
<metadata></metadata>
<resultset fetch-size="1" count="1">
    <record>
        <field name="Ident"><data>422</data></field>
        <field name="Title"><data>title text here</data></field>
        <field name="Content"><data>some more text here</data></field>
        <relatedset table="Footnotes" count="4">
            <record>
                <field name="Footnotes::Num"><data>1</data></field>
                <field name="Footnotes::Title"><data>footnote 1 text here</data></field>
            </record>
            <record>
                <field name="Footnotes::Num"><data>2</data></field>
                <field name="Footnotes::Title"><data>footnote 2 text here</data></field>
            </record>
            <record>
                <field name="Footnotes::Num"><data>3</data></field>
                <field name="Footnotes::Title"><data>footnote 3 text here</data></field>
            </record>
            <record>
                <field name="Footnotes::Num"><data>4</data></field>
                <field name="Footnotes::Title"><data>footnote 4 text here</data></field>
            </record>
        </relatedset>
        <relatedset table="Images" count="2">
            <record>
                <field name="Images::Num"><data>457</data></field>
                <field name="Images::FileName"><data>image 1 url here</data></field>
                <field name="Images::Title"><data>title for image 1 here</data></field>
            </record>
            <record>
                <field name="Images::Num"><data>563</data></field>
                <field name="Images::FileName"><data>image 2 url here</data></field>
                <field name="Images::Title"><data>title for image 2 here</data></field>
            </record>
        </relatedset>
    </record>
</resultset>
```

This is my how my XSL transformation looks so far. It works fine, but not for the "relatedset" sections.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fmp="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult" exclude-result-prefixes="fmp">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="kMetaData" match="fmp:METADATA/fmp:FIELD" use="count(preceding-sibling::fmp:FIELD) + 1" />

  <xsl:template match="/fmp:FMPXMLRESULT">
    <fmresultset version="1.0">
    <error code="0"/>
    <product build="01/01/201" name="FileMaker Web Pro" version="8.5"/>
    <datasource database="pro_page.fp7" date-format="MM/dd/yyyy" layout="MR_Page_Fr" table="pro_page" time-format="HH:mm:ss" timestamp-format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" total-count="1"/>
    <metadata></metadata>
    <resultset count="1" fetch-size="1">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:RESULTSET/fmp:ROW" />
    </resultset>
   </fmresultset>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fmp:ROW">
    <record record-id="0" mod-id="0">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL" />
    </record>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="fmp:COL">
  <field name="{string(key('kMetaData', position())/@NAME)}">
    <data><xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" /></data>
  </field>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Anybody is XSLT savvy enough to help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your goal? Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Well I know it sound silly, but my filemaker XML is stored in a MySql database with the "fmresultset " format. To update this XML it works fine with the regular FileMaker Web Publishing Engine via php (the WPE uses the "fmresultset" format).
But my ISP is shuting down the WPE server, so I'm left with the XML export function in FileMaker Pro, and there is no fmresultset option there. With a XSL file I could transform the FmPro "fmpxmlresult" format to "fmresultset" in one click... almost...

Comment: You're right, that does sound silly :-) - but at least it sounds like what you're doing is the right way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [the file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9175169/XMLRESULT-to-fmresultset.xslt); it's too long, so I post a link. I'm not 100%-sure it's correct `fmresultset` grammar though; if you can send me the DTD for it, I'll try to check.

Comment: Here is [the dtd](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/86462334/fmresultset.dtd) for the fmresultset grammar

Comment: I've made more tests and your XSLT file is working perfectly for transforming the FMPXMLRESULT xml grammar to FMRESULTSET. A really good job indeed!

This XSLT file should be saved somewhere in the FileMaker web site, this is too precious to leave it only here in a forum...

Comment: @Ludwig: Thanks :) I tested it against the DTD and made two small fixes (e.g. I have to supply fake record IDs for portal records); here's the [new link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9175169/FMPXMLRESULT-to-fmresultset.xslt). By the way it has its uses outside of the web; e.g. I use it to make complex exports (e.g. Excel XML), it's much more convenient to work with than FMPXMLRESULT.